# DOMPDF no renderiza imagen del servidor

Tags: php, dompdf

Estoy usando la librería `dompdf` para imprimir reportes, pero no quiere renderizar la imagen y solo me muestra una X, aquí el código:

```html
echo"<img src='$imageURL = /roda/img/.$row[ruta_imagen]'/>";
```

Comment: Por qué usas el tag [sql] ? Sugiero un fragmento más amplio del código para ver, digamos, de dónde viene $row

Comment: @Alfabravo    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: Si código no se puede ayudar, no somos adivinos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir el código relevante. Y la x es la respuesta estándar de un navegador cuando no carga la imagen, así que seguro la URL está mal. Mira tu navegador y al menos revisa qué queda en el atributo src cuando cargas esta página.

Comment: etiquetas editadas. De las que hubo, sólo 2 eran acertadas. Saludos :D

Comment: @fredyfx gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás poniendo mal el código, lo que tienes ahora:

```
echo"<img src='$imageURL = /roda/img/.$row[ruta_imagen]'/>";
```

Tiene varios problemas:

1. Tal y como estás escribiendo, el `src` generado va a ser como sigue:

   ```
   "VALOR_DE_IMAGEURL = /roda/img/.VALOR_DE_ROW_RUTA_IMAGEN"
   ```

   por ejemplo, si el valor inicial de `$imageURL` era "" y el del `$row["ruta_imagen"]` era "flor.jpg", entonces el código generado será:

   ```
   " = /roda/img/.flor.jpg"
   ```

   que no es una ruta válida por lo que verás la X o la imagen por defecto para imágenes que no se cargaron bien.
2. `$row[ruta_imagen]` dará un warning porque `ruta_imagen` no es nada a menos que lo hayas definido antes. Debería ir entre comillas `$row["ruta_imagen"]`... pero te va a funcionar porque PHP no encuentra la constante/variable `ruta_imagen` y entonces lo interpreta como la cadena "ruta_imagen".
3. Estás concatenando mal los valores, aunque esto se puede solucionar de una mejor manera moviendo la asignación de `$imageURL` a antes del `echo`:

   ```
   $imageURL = "/roda/img/" . $row["ruta_imagen"];
   echo "<img src='$imageURL'/>";
   ```

Con ese último código, ya te debería funcionar (si la imagen existe y está en la ruta especificada).

Comment: gracias alvaro, lo acabo de hacer pero, fire fox me proyecta las imagenes pero no descarga el pdf de forma correcta, como si estuviera corrupto el archivo y el chrome simplemente no lo despliega

Comment: @LeonardoRodríguez entonces, ¿ahora sí se ve la imagen pero no se abre el PDF cuando pulsas en la imagen? Si es eso, sería una pregunta totalmente diferente y deberías crear una nueva publicación donde tendrás que incluir el código con el que generas el PDF.

Comment: gracias, te puse ganchito, está atento, durante el dia publicare la pregunta.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170827/dompdf-no-renderiza-el-archivo