# DOMPDF no renderiza el archivo

Tags: php, html, dompdf

Tengo este script que no está renderizando de forma correcta, firefox lo muestra pero cuando intento descargar el  pdf me sale archivo corrupto.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">


</style>

</head>
<body  >

<?php

   
 ob_start();

    include('config.php');
   /* $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*******"); 
    mysql_select_db("roda", $link);*/
       if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
  $id=$_GET['id'];
 
    
 }
 
 $sq = "SELECT * from caso WHERE bl = '$id' ORDER BY id_bl DESC LIMIT 5";
  $result1 = mysqli_query($connex, $sq);
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
   {
   $bl3=$row2['bl'];
   $bl4=$row2['nom_cli'];
   $bl5=$row2['cod_cli'];
   $bl6=$row2['fech'];
   $bl7=$row2['origen'];
       $bl8=$row2['cant'];
   $bl9=$row2['alm'];
   $bl10=$row2['ret'];
   $bl11=$row2['coment'];
   }
    
    echo"   <head> <style type='text/css'>

.logo{
 position: relative;
    right: 50 px;
 width:75 px; 
 
 
}
body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
 font-size: 8px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>  ";
    
      echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />";
      echo"<img src='logo2.jpg' class='logo' />";
   
   echo"<center>Informe de carga detallada Fecha/Hora.</center>";
    echo'<hr>';
    echo'<br>'; 

   
   echo '<table  border="0" cellpadding="4" align="" cellspacing="0" >';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td  align="right"><b>Número de caso:</b></td>';
   echo"<td  style='color:red'  >$bl3 </td>";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td  align="right"><b>Cliente:</b></td>';
   echo"<td style='color:red'>$bl4</td>";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td><b>Codigo de cliente:</b></td>';
   echo"<td>$bl5</td>";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';  
   echo'<td><b>Fecha de creación:</b></td>';
   echo"<td>$bl6</td>"; 
 echo '</tr>'; 
 echo'<tr>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td  align="right"><b>Origen:</b></td>';
   echo"<td>$bl7</td>";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    echo'<td><b>Cantidad de items:</b></td>';
   echo"<td>$bl8</td>";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td><b>Almacenamiento:</b></td>';
   echo"<td>$bl9</td>"; 
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td align="right"><b>Retención:</b></td>';
   echo"<td>$bl10</td>"; 
  echo'</tr>'; 
 echo'<tr>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td align="right"><b>Comentario:</b></td>';
   echo"<td>$bl11</td>";
   echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>'; 
   echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>'; 
  echo'</tr>'; 
 echo'</table>';
echo "<br>";

echo"<hr></hr>";

   
   
   
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM acarga WHERE bl3 = '$id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connex, $sql);
  echo' <table  width="100%" height="99" border="0" >';
  echo '<tr>'; 
 echo'   <th>&nbsp;</th>';
  echo'  <th>&nbsp;</th>';
   echo' <th>Cód item</th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield3"></label></th>';
   echo' <th></th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield4"></label></th>';
   echo' <th>Cód camión</th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield5"></label></th>';
   echo' <th>Tipo P.A.</th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield6"></label></th>';
   echo' <th>Código P.A.</th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield7"></label></th>';
   echo' <th>Destino</th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield8"></label></th>';
    echo'<th>Estado de carga</th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield9"></label></th>';
   echo' <th>Fecha</th>';
   echo' <th><label for="textfield10"></label></th>';
   echo' <th>Hora</th>';
    echo'<th>&nbsp;</th>';
   echo' <th>Comentario</th>';
   echo' <th>&nbsp;</th>';
   echo' <th>Foto</th>';
   echo' <th>&nbsp;</th>';
   echo '</tr>'; 
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
 $a=$row['cod_it'];
 $b=$row['bl3'];
 $c=$row['uni_ca'];
 $d=$row['tipo_pa'];
 $e=$row['num_int'];
 $f=$row['dest'];
 $g=$row['estado'];
 $h=$row['fecha'];
 $i=$row['hora'];
 $j=$row['comenta'];
    //$k=$row['ruta_imagen'];
 //$imageURL = $row['ruta_imagen'];
$imageURL = "img/".$row["ruta_imagen"];

 echo'<tr>';
  echo'<td></td>';
  echo'<td></td>';
  echo"<td align='center' > $a </td>   ";
  echo'<td></td>';
  echo"<td  align='center' > </td>   ";
  echo'<td></td>';
  echo"<td align='center' > $c </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo"<td align='center' > $d </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo"<td align='center' > $e </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo"<td align='center' > $f </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo"<td align='center' > $g </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo"<td align='center' > $h </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo"<td  align='center' > $i </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo"<td  align='center' > $j </td>   ";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
//echo"<td img src='img/$imageURL'> </td>";
 ?>
 
<td> <?php echo "<img src='$imageURL'/>";
 ?>  </td>
 
 
 <?php 
// echo"<td> <img src='/var/www/roda/img/noimage.jpg' /> </td>";
  echo'<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo'</tr>';
   
   
   }
   
  echo' </table>';

 ?>     

<?php
 
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait');

$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$filename =".$bl3.".pdf;
$dompdf->stream($filename, array("Attachment" =>0));

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seguro necesitas hacer `output()` antes del `stream()` ?

Comment: No termina de quedar claro cómo lo estás poniendo en la página. Si lo generas así y lo escribes te debería dar problemas porque ya se han enviado las cabeceras, si lo estás generando en un fichero aparte, no estás añadiendo enlace o nada para que se muestre. Definitivamente falta algo

Comment: Explicame que debo hacer, soy novato en esto

Comment: Hay varias cosas llamativas que te deberían estar dando problemas. Por ejemplo, `$filename =".$bl3.".pdf;` es una línea que te tiene que lanzar warnings y errores en PHP (además de que no va a generar el nombre que esperas). Te recomendaría que pusieras un `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio de tu PHP y ver qué mensajes te aparecen para corregirlos.